# How to get a SAML Response from OKTA for unit/integration testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing, saml, okta

I am working on project where they are authenticating via SAML from OKTA.  I have successfully got the integration working where a SAMLResponse sent (via POST method) to the website.

In true TDD fashion, I started by writing some unit tests.  My unit tests take in a SAMLResponse (which is Base64 encoded).  All my unit tests work, however, because a SAMLResponse only have a lifetime (expires) of a few minutes, my unit tests break after a few minutes.

So I need to periodically login to OKTA, then using Chrome dev tools capture the traffic being sent to my dev site.  I then copy and paste the SAMLResponse into my unit tests and get back to passing unit tests.  Obviously this is not a desirable situation.

So my question is how can I login to Okta in an automated fashion (preferably in C#) to get a SAMLResponse?  I assume there is some URL I can POST to with username and password and get back the SAMLReponse.  All my Fiddler attempts at trying to understand the required communicate has left me frustrated.  I am looking for any guidance you might have.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SAML, but from your question I think that you are either testing at the incorrect level or need further abstraction. I would see it that where you process the Response shouldn't matter on the actual message but more on the content of the message, i.e being able to fake the response should work. I would never expect a unit test to have to ever call an external function and it would ring alarms if it had to login to an external application.

Comment: Agreed.  This really is becoming an integration test now.  If SAMLResponses didn't expire it could truly be a unit test, but according to Okta that is not an option.  Given the complexity of SAML integration, we rely on our tests to find configuration problems on a weekly basis.

Comment: Regarding your comment about being able to "fake" the response.  That was what I originally tried, however responses (which are just Base 64 strings) contain certificate signed information.  So if you change anything the response, the validation will fail.  I know I am breaking some unit test best practices, but I am also backed into a corner by SAML and OKTA but still not going to give up on my integration tests as I derive so much value from them... just want them to be automated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have come up with a working solution and wanted to share it with the community.  *I am not sure of the protocol for answering my own question based on useful feedback from other authors (Joël Franusic).  If I am breaking protocol, please let me know.*

Thanks to Joël Franusic for the pointers.  I implemented his 1.2 solution (User Agent with Okta client)  Between his references and a few other pieces of documentation on the Okta website, I was able to eventually piece together working code.

```
private static async Task<string> GetTestSamlResponse()
    {
        try
        {
            // settings specific to my Okta instance
            string username = "USERNAME GOES HERE";
            string password = "PASSWORD GOES HERE";
            var apiToken = "API TOKEN GOES HERE";

            // this is the unique domain issued to your account.  
            // If you setup a dev account you'll have a domain in the form https://dev-<AccountNumber>.oktapreview.com.
            // account number is a unique number issues by Okta when you sign up for the account
            var baseUrl = "YOUR BASE URL GOES HERE";

            // In Okta Admin UI, click "Applications" in main menu, choose your app, click "Sign On" tab.  Under Sign On Methods, then under SAML 2.0, click "View Setup Instructions"
            // Get the url called "Identity Provider Single Sign-On URL", paste it in th below line
            var ssoUrl = "YOUR SSO URL GOES HERE";

            // construct an Okta settings object
            var settings = new Okta.Core.OktaSettings
            {
                ApiToken = apiToken,
                BaseUri = new Uri(baseUrl)
            };

            // get session token from Okta
            var authClient = new Okta.Core.Clients.AuthClient(settings);
            var authResponse = authClient.Authenticate(username, password);
            var sessionToken = authResponse.SessionToken;

            // start session and get a cookie token
            var sessionsClient = new Okta.Core.Clients.SessionsClient(settings);
            var session = sessionsClient.CreateSession(sessionToken);
            var cookieToken = session.CookieToken;

            // using the cookie token, get the SAMLResponse from Okta via a HTTP GET.
            var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

            // add User-Agent header, because apparently Okta is expecting this information.  
            // If you don't pass something, the Okta site will return a 500 - Internal Server error
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "UnitTest");

            // add the cookie token to the URL query string
            string url = string.Format("{0}?onetimetoken={1}", ssoUrl, cookieToken);

            // do the HTTP GET
            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    // read the HTML returned
                    string html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    // parse the HTML to get the SAMLResponse (using HtmlAgilityPack from NuGet)
                    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
                    // from the input field called SAMLResponse, get the "value" attribute
                    string samlResponse = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='SAMLResponse']").Attributes["value"].Value;
                    return samlResponse;
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Error getting SAML Response {0}", response.StatusCode));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do the kind of testing that you suggest, here are what come to mind immediately:

1. Write a simple HTTP "User Agent" in C# using a library like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) or similar.
2. Build an integration test against an external mock IdP.
3. Modify the `SAMLResponse` and re-sign with your own key.

I cover each approach in detail below.

**Writing a simple HTTP "User Agent"**

I suggest this method, I suggest taking one of following two approaches:

1. Write a generic User Agent that will detect and fill out username and password form fields. I wrote a tool in Python called "[saml-messenger](https://bitbucket.org/jfranusic/saml-messenger)" that takes this approach, the core code is in the file named [messenger.py](https://bitbucket.org/jfranusic/saml-messenger/src/06cc23773f577dc5635f63ffb752e7688d04d503/messenger.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#messenger.py-193:233).
2. Use the Okta's API to fetch a session token and use that to get a `SAMLResponse`. The [okta-aws-cli-assume-role](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-aws-cli-assume-role/) project takes this approach. The code for [fetching the session token](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-aws-cli-assume-role/blob/master/src/main/java/com/okta/tools/awscli.java#L1400-L1489) and [exchanging that session token for a SAMLResponse](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-aws-cli-assume-role/blob/master/src/main/java/com/okta/tools/awscli.java#L334-L361) are both found in the `src/main/java/com/okta/tools/awscli.java` file.

The first approach is more generic and should work with any IdP with a username and password field. The second approach is likely what you're looking for, but is specific to Okta.

In either case, I suggest making a special user in Okta that is locked down and used only for testing.

**Building an integration test against an a mock IdP**

This approach would have you set up a mock IdP that would give you a `SAMLResponse` without authentication, I've used the [saml-idp](https://github.com/mcguinness/saml-idp) project to do this before.

The upside to this approach is that it *should* require less C# for you to write, at the expense of taking on another dependency.

**Modifying an re-signing a `SAMLResponse`**

I'm really only including this option here for the sake of completeness and as a way to warn you against trying this approach. Learning about SAML will put you face to face with insanity and regret. I do not suggest this approach.